# Why is the conversion from EST to UTC +5 hours and not +4?

Tags: datetime, timezone, timezone-offset, pytz

My goal is to convert a tz-aware object to a different timezone.
For example - consider the code below where I have a tz-aware object in timezone `'US/Eastern'`:

```
import pytz
from datetime import timedelta

datetime_est = datetime(2020, 7, 10, 9, 23, 53, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
```

The problem is that when I print the `timestamp` like this: `datetime_est.timestamp()` (which should be UTC) I get 2020 July 10 14:19:53. This is +5 hours.

Why +5 when the same time in UTC should be +4?

Comment: Don't assign the time zone directly.  Use the `localize` function.  See the answer in the duplicate.  This is also one of the very first things in the pytz docs. ;)

Comment: Thank you! Yes the duplicate covers it. I knew it was asked somewhere already and I thought it may be the `localize` but the word `local` kind of sounds not very intuitive for thins kind of thing... Anyway, thanks!

Comment: FYI - pytz is fine, but the `dateutil` package is more modern and intuitive for this sort of thing.  See https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#tzfile-examples.  Also, [PEP-615](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0615/) adds built-in support to Python for this.  It is available in Python 3.9 beta 1 and greater.

Comment: Ideally i would like to not use pytz. I will give the documentation a good read. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I pointed at the wrong place.  Use `gettz` function, as shown here: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.gettz  The files themselves come from the OS.

Comment: Okay, I read thorough it now, however I don't get how do we apply this to actually change the tz of a datetime object (or is it more accurate to say to view it in a different tz)?

Comment: Actually I think I figured how to do that, so more the question now is (compared to `pytz`) how do I `localize` with `dateutil.tz` before I add the time zone?